# Can't send key combinations with TeamViewer from Mac OS X to another Mac OS X

Tags: macos, mac, remote-access, teamviewer

For some reason I can't send key combinations from my MacBook to my Mac Pro. I tried from a PC and it works, only from my MacBook seems to fail.

Does anyone have any idea what the hell it's going on?

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Apparently you can't send key combinations that are "Mac OSX Shortcuts."

[image: Apparently you can't send every shortcut you want.]

Comment: Technically Apple isn't preventing this feature. I say this because, Logme In Pro does Cmd-tab task switching flawlessly